# Redirect Alternative Domain Names for a Web Site While Maintaining Request Integrity

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

We bought some domain names that are similar to the primary domain name for our Web Site. All of these alternative domain names are associated with a single VirtualHost of which I can edit the single .htaccess file for.

What I want in the redirection implementation is integrity to the protocol of the initial request, and also any and all of the string after the initial request's TLD (like /images/smile.jpg). I also want the literal integrity of that path too. I believe this requires the 'NE' tag.

For the specific examples see: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=K99wxW7J

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a script on the site that is redirecting. DNS is not smart enough for what you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I am using my .htaccess file, not DNS for the redirection.

Comment: Is the setup like a wildcard sub domain/domain?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say

Comment: Is your sub domains set up like this: `*.example.com`? Or are they manually added?

Comment: I have like 50 subdomains on the main domain name. But thanks for the help.